# Ionic: How do I include header from one page when I navigate to another page?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 and on my Home Page, I have the following code. When I click the searchMore button, it navigates to a new page. I want to include "Cook With What is in My Pantry" from the h5 on the new page.

```
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-9>
      <h5 name="cookWith">Cook With What is in My Pantry</h5>
    </ion-col>
    <div class="applyMore">
      <ion-col col-3>
        <button (click)="searchMore()" ion-button clear icon-left>
          More
        <ion-icon name='arrow-forward'></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </div>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

On the page it links to, I have the following code where I want the h5 to appear.

```
<h5 name="cookWith">{{cookWith}}</h5>
```

In my .TS files, I have the following

From Homepage

```
  export class HomePage {constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
  public navParams:          
  NavParams) {

   }

  /**
  *links filter button to FilterPage
  */

 recipeFilter(event, button) {
   this.navCtrl.push(FilterPage, {
   button: button
   });
   }

  searchMore(event, button) {
    this.navCtrl.push(RecipesearchPage, {
    });
    ;
   }
  }
```

Page it links to

```
export class RecipesearchPage {

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
 NavParams) {   
 } 

 ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad RecipesearchPage');
 }

 /**
 *on click, links from recipe card to individual recipe page
 */
 individualRecipe() {
  this.navCtrl.push(RecipePage);
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you could do it this way. If you need to change the string in the future you can change it in the constructor.  I think if it is static and won't change why not just have it in both places?

#### Option #1:  If you need to update the label dynamically later.

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-9>
      <h5>{{cookWith}}</h5>
    </ion-col>
    <div class="applyMore">
      <ion-col col-3>
        <button (click)="searchMore()" ion-button clear icon-left>
          More
          <ion-icon name='arrow-forward'></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </div>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Add in the declaration of the value on the main component class:

```
export class HomePage {
  cookWith: string;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams
  ){
     this.cookWith = 'Cook With What is in My Pantry';
  }

  /**
   *links filter button to FilterPage
   */
   recipeFilter(event, button) {
      this.navCtrl.push(FilterPage, { 
         button: button
      });
   }

   searchMore(event, button) {
     this.navCtrl.push(RecipesearchPage, {
        cookWith: this.cookWith
     });
   }
}
```

then you pick it up on the other side:

```
export class RecipesearchPage {
  cookWith: string;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams
  ){
    this.cookWith = navParams.get('cookWith');
  } 

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RecipesearchPage');
  }

  /**
   *on click, links from recipe card to individual recipe page
   */
   individualRecipe() {
     this.navCtrl.push(RecipePage);
   };
 }
```

#### Option #2:  Just put the html in both places:

```
 <h5>Cook With What is in My Pantry</h5>
```

Comment: I  implemented it and got the following error:  Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'cookWith'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.cookWith'?
src/pages/recipesearch/recipesearch.ts
){
  cookWith = navParams.get('cookWith');
}

Comment: when I change cookWith to this.cookWith destination typescript page, the error goes away  but now no h5 appears in either the from or destination html page

Comment: I have updated the code to have this.cookWith in the constructor to assign value to the variable.

Comment: Hey so I would suggest looking at my solution again.  I updated with the navparam.  I was passing undefined because this.cookWith wasn't being passed as a parameter to the push of the navcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of reusing same header in multiple pages in ionic/angular is via `directive`